# What is the US style to list the advisor's name of a master's thesis?

Tags: thesis, cv, united-states

In listing my master's thesis in CV I came across this problem: Should I put the name of my advisor in front of my name or should I put only my name (I have my advisor's name printed in my thesis) according to the US style?

Comment: _Should I put the name of my advisor in front of my name_ — No, of course not!  It's **your** thesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to be too formal here. Just include whatever information you believe is relevant, for example:

> Master's Thesis: "Topic", at University X, supervised by Prof. Y.

Theses are different from regular publications anyway.

Answer (score 2):

At least with the APA style, the advisor's name is not included.  The example from the fifth edition of APA (my 6th edition is lent out) is:

Almeida, D. M. (1990) *Fathers' participation in family work: Consequences for fathers' stress and father-child relations.* Unpublished master's thesis, University of Victoria, Victoria, British Columbia, Canada.

With a hanging indent that I can't figure out how to do here.